# Bootstrap Tab Activation with URL

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this for java script to activate a bootstrap tab on page load when the url looks like this this: `/settings#update` for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     var url = document.location.toString();
     var url2 = url.split('#')[1];

     var script = '#myTab a[href="#'+url2+'"]';

     $(script).tab('show');

    })
</script>
```

My html is this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo __('settings:general') ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="#identities" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo __("settings:business_identities") ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="#update" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo __('global:update') ?></a></li>
  </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
    ... 
 </div>
```

When this all runs, I get this error on this line: `$(script).tab('show');`

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I have this working in jsfiddle. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/3/  .As to your problem, you might be loading the javascript code before the DOM elements load.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `#` in the url the `script` variable is undefined.
You need to check for this case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     var url = document.location.toString();
     if(url.match('#')!=null){
        var url2 = url.split('#')[1];
        var script = '#myTab a[href="#'+url2+'"]';
        $(script).tab('show');
     }

   })
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is a `#` or not. I get the error.

Comment: Have you placed the script(s) file(s) in a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your  is BELOW all your other html content. Make sure the DOM is properly loaded before you try to manipulate it with the scripts. You can also wrap your function in $(document).ready() to make sure DOM is loaded. As mentioned before in a comment, the code works fine.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/4/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary">a0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#identities" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary">a1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#update" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-primary">a2</a></li>
  </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
    ... 
 </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function({
    var url = "costam#active"
     var url2 = url.split('#')[1];

     var script = '#myTab a[href="#'+url2+'"]';

     $(script).tab('show');
    }));
</script>
```